# Is it possible to define a callable concept that includes functions and lambdas?

Tags: c++, lambda, type-traits, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to define a concept that would accept all callable objects.
Here's what I have done so far:

```cpp
template<typename F>
concept Func = std::is_function_v<std::remove_pointer_t<std::decay_t<F>>> || (requires (F f) {
    std::is_function_v<decltype(f.operator())>;
});

bool is_callable(Func auto&&) {
    return true;
}

bool is_callable(auto&&) {
    return false;
}
```

Yet if I define those:

```cpp
auto f = [](auto a, auto b, auto c, auto d, auto e) {
    return a * b * c * d * e;
};

int g(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

`is_callable(g)` is `true` but `is_callable(f)` is `false`, it did not work (I want both to return `true`).

So I tried to see if the following would compile:

```cpp
decltype(f.operator()) // Reference to non-static member function must be called
decltype(&f.operator()) // Cannot create a non-constant pointer to member function
decltype(f::operator()) // 'f' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
decltype(&f::operator()) // same as previously
```

It gave me the errors you can see as comment on those 4 lines.

Is there a way to check is f has a valid functor which would mean f is a lambda?

Is there a better solution to what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: "*I want to define a concept that would accept all callable objects.*" When you're starting to define a concept, start with writing the code that would *use* the concept. I can't imagine how a "callable" concept is useful *without* at least an argument list. How do you plan to use the callable object if you don't know what arguments it is legal to give it?

Comment: Also, why are you making `is_callable` a function rather than it just being the concept itself?

Comment: Well yes, I want to use this with curryfied function (I implemented curryfication with concepts just fine) which makes it hard (or impossible) to get a argument list.

Comment: As for the is_callable I just found it more readable to present it that way, and so that the code compiles and does not just give an error.

Comment: "*which makes it hard (or impossible) to get a argument list.*" At some point, *somebody* has to have an argument list in order to actually use the function. That's the point when you apply the concept.

Comment: `curry(f)(1, 2)()(3)(4, 5)` yes eventually it will get called with arguments, and eventually I call f with all arguments, it would fail if f is not callable yes. I was just wondering if I could make a concept just to make it more rigorous and to display better error messages (which I think is part of why concepts exist). Even If it is not very useful, I would like to know if it is possible or impossible.

Comment: Without having an argument list given to `curry(f)`, how would the resulting curry functor know that `f` takes 5 arguments?

Answer (score 5):

What you want is not possible (or a good idea, but nevermind that now).

A "function" by name in C++ represents potentially many functions. It represents overloads, template instantiations through template argument deduction, etc. But to get a function *pointer*, you are required to peer through all of that. If the name represents an overload set, to get a pointer, you have to cast that name to a specific overload. If the name represents a template, you have to provide the template arguments to denote a specific instantiation.

What that means is that, by the time your hypothetical `is_callable` concept gets to be invoked on a function pointer type, all of the overload resolution and template substitution has already happened. It is given a single pointer to a specific, well-defined piece of code which can be called with a signature defined by the type of that pointer.

None of that is the case for a function *object*. A functor (whether generated by a C++ lambda expression or just a hand-written type) is nothing more than a type with an `operator()` overload. And that overload is just a function name, exactly like any other name: subject to rules of overload resolution and template substitution.

C++ does not allow you to ask the question "here's a name; can I call this with *something*?"

And broadly speaking, that's just not a useful question to ask.

Whether you're using this "callable" concept for currying or whathaveyou, *at some point*, some piece of code is going to call some function with some set of arguments, which will eventually cascade into calling the given function with another set of argument defined by some process. *That is the point* when you need to constrain the given callable.

Constraining the function at the site where you're building the curried callable is useless. You have no idea if there's a type mismatch between arguments and return values, or anything of the kind. You will only know that when you're given a set of arguments to use to call the curried callable. That's the place when you can compute the arguments to eventually call the proper function, so that's where the constraining should happen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer even though I disagree on the fact it has to be useful to be worth defining.

Comment: @titarch: Why would you want a useless thing in a language? C++ already has plenty of features of dubious merit; we don't need more ;)

Comment: Well I just like to define useless things just to prove that it is feasible, to see if the language allows such things, I am quite fascinated by languages on a meta level (I might just be crazy).

Comment: *"C++ does not allow you to ask the question "here's a name; can I call this with something?""* We can do it with non final classes, see [the answer in related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62399638/2684539).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest (and use):

```cpp
template<typename LMB, typename...ARGS>
concept callable_with_args = requires( LMB&& lmb, std::function<void(ARGS...)> f )
{
    { f = std::move( lmb ) }; // lambda can be moved to func of good type.
};
```

use for example in:

```cpp
void somefunc( callable_with_args<int,string> auto&& fn ) {...}
void somefunc( callable_with_args<int>        auto&& fn ) {...}
```

(particularly when we have a large overload set, and where a generic `somefunc(auto&& lmb)` would be painful to constrain.)

Bonus: static unit tests ;-)

```cpp
static_assert(  callable_with_args<decltype([]{})> );
static_assert(  callable_with_args<decltype([](int){}),int> );
static_assert( !callable_with_args<decltype([]{}),int> );
static_assert( !callable_with_args<decltype([](int){})> );
```

Note1: This probably work with more things than lambdas...

Note2: You asked for *concept*, so obviously this is C++20 code !

Answer (score 1):

I would propose a similar solution to [Steve's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61643155/16770597) that only relies on the "type_traits" header:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename F, typename R, typename... Args>
concept callable = std::same_as<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>, R>;

template<typename F>
concept runnable = callable<F, void>;

template<typename F, typename R>
concept supplier = callable<F, R>;

template<typename F, typename... Args>
concept consumer = callable<F, void, Args...>;

template<typename F, typename... Args>
concept predicate = callable<F, bool, Args...>;
```

A simple use case:

```cpp
#include <span>

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
auto test_all(std::span<T, Size> values, predicate<T> auto &&test) {
    for (const auto &value : values) {
        if (not test(value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool is_even(int number) {
    return number % 2 == 0;
}

int main() {
    const auto values = std::array{ 0, 2, 4 };
    const auto span = std::span{ values };

    test_all(span, is_even);
    test_all(span, &is_even);
    test_all(span, [&values](int value) {
        return value == values[0];
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why callable has the F parameter ? What does it do ? Wouldn't it be easier if we could just type `callable<int, bool>` for a function that could take in a bool and return an int ?

Comment: The confusion comes from the way concepts with extra type parameters are written.
The callable as well as all the other concept get the function type to be tested as the first parameter followed by the extra types (in this case to specify the return type and parameters).
So if you write a template like `template<callable<int, bool> F>` the concept will be instantiated like `callable<F, int, bool>`, exactly like you proposed.